# Data entry problem with incorrect result?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Seeing the code.
When I start the program, it doesn't let me insert the scanner class input into the switch, how come?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("select:");
int select = in.nextInt();

switch (select) {
case 1:
System.out.println("first name:");
String n = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("surname:");
String s = in.nextLine();

System.out.println(n + s);
break;
}
```

Output:

select:
1
first name:
surname:

Comment: Need more information about "it doesn't let me insert the scanner class input into the switch"... we know what you want to happen, but we don't know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The nextLine method is ignored because there is a newline character left in the nextInt method. There are two ways to fix this problem.

Solution 1:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("select:");
int select = in.nextInt();

in.nextLine();
```

Solution 2:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("select:");
int select = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `Scanner` with `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` could fix it, try:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("select:");
int select = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

switch (select) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("first name:");
        String n = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        System.out.println("surname:");
        String s = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        System.out.println(n + s);
    break;
}
```